# Font Size in FireDac SQL Editor

Tags: delphi, firedac

Embarcadero provided syntax highlighting in the FireDAC SQL editor with the current Delphi 11.2 version.  I am using Delphi 11.2 Professional on an HP Spectre x360 with a 4K display.  The font size in the editor is tiny, and I can't find anything in the Options settings to change it. Can the font size for this editor be changed, and if it can, where can I find the setting?

Comment: No setting. The issue has been reported to Embarcadero (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39043).

Comment: Recently I attached zip to RSP-39043 with package which is workaround for this issue. It will restore TMemo in FireDAC design-time editors and will resolve the issue.